# Count the occurrence of success and failed based on the status of each datapoint

Tags: javascript

Given an array of datapoints. I want to be able to count the occurrence of a datapoint x by the status of each point. The datapoint can exist more than once. The goal is to keep a count for each point and finally return an object of each point and the failure and successful count

For example. Given an array

```
const data = [
        {
            "x": 14,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-14T14:23:59.825Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 14,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-14T14:27:51.666Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-15T10:34:07.317Z",
            "status": "success"
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-15T10:34:08.601Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-15T10:34:09.871Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-15T10:34:11.108Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-15T10:35:17.969Z",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-15T11:10:59.600Z",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-15T11:22:29.020Z",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-15T11:48:15.974Z",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T09:56:30.156Z",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:49:55.734Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:49:56.707Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:49:57.692Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:49:58.620Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:49:59.638Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:50:00.561Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:11:13.602Z",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:11:41.271Z",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:12:06.548Z",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:26:02.834Z",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:27:05.462Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T12:11:21.446Z",
            "status": "undefined"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T12:12:18.397Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-16T12:22:05.958Z",
            "status": "accepted"
        },
        {
            "x": 18,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:06:57.946Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 18,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:06:59.179Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 18,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:07:00.375Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 18,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:07:01.534Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 18,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:07:02.633Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 18,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:07:03.732Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 20,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:17.967Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 20,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:19.073Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 20,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:20.000Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 20,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:21.008Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 20,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:21.972Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        },
        {
            "x": 20,
            "y": "1",
            "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:22.946Z",
            "status": "undelivered"
        }
    ]
```

I want to be able to get result as

```
result = {
   14: {
     failureCount: 2,
     successCount : 0,
     total: 2
   },
   15: {
     failureCount: 7,
     successCount : 1,
     total: 8
   }
   .......
}
```

failureCount is incremented when status is not equal to delivered or success i.e

```
element.status !== "delivered" || element.status !== "success"

where element is the item in each array
```

successCount is incremented when status is equal to delivered or success i.e

```
element.status == "delivered" || element.status == "success"

where element is the item in each array
```

total is the summation of the y datapoint

Attempt

```
const map = {};
let failureCount = 0;
let successCount = 0;
data.forEach((element, index) => {
  map[element.x] = {
    failureCount: failureCount,
    successCount: successCount
  }
  const failed = element.status !== "delivered" || element.status !== "success"
  if(element.x in map && failed){
    map[element.x] = {
      failureCount: map[element.x].failureCount + 1
    }
  }else {
    map[element.x] = {
      successCount: map[element.x].successCount + 1
    }
  }
})
```

Based on the comments, came up with a slightly modified solution of my original attempt

```
const map = {};
data.forEach((element, index) => {
  if(!map[element.x]){
   map[element.x] = {
    failureCount: 0,
    successCount: 0
   }
  }

  const failed = element.status !== "delivered" && element.status !== "success"
  if(failed){
    map[element.x].failureCount +=1
  }else {
    map[element.x].successCount +=1;
  }
})

console.log(map)
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: added that to the question

Comment: 1) You are overwriting `map[element.x]` in every loop. You only need to assign a new object the first time for a particular `x` i.e. if `map[element.x]` is undefined. `if(!map[element.x]) map[element.x] = { failureCount:. ... }`2) `failed` will always be `true`. No string can be equal to `"delivered"` and `"success"` at the same time. You need `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: Came up with a modified solution of my original attempt based on the answers and comments. Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issues

The `failure` condition isn't right.

```
const failed = element.status !== "delivered" || element.status !== "success"
```

If `element.status` is `'success'`, `failed` will be `true` since `element.status !== "delivered"` returns true.

It should instead be

```
const failed = element.status !== 'delivered' && element.status !== 'success'
```

And you're reassigning `map[element.x]` every time. You should instead use the object if it exists in `map` or initialize it to a default object with the keys (`failureCount`, `successCount`, and `total`) set to 0.

#### Solution

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the result object. You can initialize the object for each element with `{ failureCount: 0, successCount: 0, total: 0 }` if it doesn't already exist in the accumulator (`acc`) object. You can then increment `failureCount` if the status is `failed` or increment `successCount`. And then you can increment `total`.

```js
const data = [ { "x": 14, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-14T14:23:59.825Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 14, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-14T14:27:51.666Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 15, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-15T10:34:07.317Z", "status": "success" }, { "x": 15, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-15T10:34:08.601Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 15, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-15T10:34:09.871Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 15, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-15T10:34:11.108Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 15, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-15T10:35:17.969Z", "status": "pending" }, { "x": 15, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-15T11:10:59.600Z", "status": "pending" }, { "x": 15, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-15T11:22:29.020Z", "status": "pending" }, { "x": 15, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-15T11:48:15.974Z", "status": "pending" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T09:56:30.156Z", "status": "pending" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:49:55.734Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:49:56.707Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:49:57.692Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:49:58.620Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:49:59.638Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T10:50:00.561Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:11:13.602Z", "status": "pending" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:11:41.271Z", "status": "pending" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:12:06.548Z", "status": "pending" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:26:02.834Z", "status": "pending" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T11:27:05.462Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T12:11:21.446Z", "status": "undefined" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T12:12:18.397Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 16, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-16T12:22:05.958Z", "status": "accepted" }, { "x": 18, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:06:57.946Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 18, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:06:59.179Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 18, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:07:00.375Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 18, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:07:01.534Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 18, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:07:02.633Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 18, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-18T18:07:03.732Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 20, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:17.967Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 20, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:19.073Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 20, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:20.000Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 20, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:21.008Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 20, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:21.972Z", "status": "undelivered" }, { "x": 20, "y": "1", "created_at": "2021-04-20T07:56:22.946Z", "status": "undelivered" } ]

const result = data.reduce((acc, { x, status }) => {
  acc[x] = acc[x] || {
    failureCount: 0,
    successCount: 0,
    total: 0,
  }

  const failed = status !== 'delivered' && status !== 'success'
  if (failed) {
    acc[x].failureCount += 1
  } else {
    acc[x].successCount += 1
  }

  acc[x].total += 1
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You could add a `total: 0` key to `acc[x]` and just do `acc[x].total++` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
const data = <ACTUAL_DATA>
const map = {}

data.forEach(item => {
    let curItem = map[item.x] || {
        failureCount: 0,
        successCount: 0,
        total: 0
    }

    if (item.status == "delivered" || item.status == "success") {
        curItem.successCount += 1
    } else {
        curItem.failureCount += 1
    }

    curItem.total += 1
    map[item.x] = curItem
})

console.log(map)
```